# Unity: How can i connect my phone to node server

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a mobile multiplayer game with Unity's socket IO a nodeJS server. when i run the mobile game from unity, it connects to the nodejs server, but when i try using my phone it doesnt connect. `ws://127.0.0.1:4000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket`

Please how can I make a connection between them ?

Comment: Replace `127.0.0.1` with the IP or FQDN of the Node server

Comment: @ivanivan doesnt 127.0.0.1 refer to the local host ? cause thats where my server is running

Comment: On the phone, localhost refers to the phone. Is your server running on the phone or your computer?

Comment: @RetiredNinja it is running on my pc

Comment: Then you need to use the PCs network address, not localhost, as mentioned by @ivanivan above.

Comment: thanks guys, it worked